# Customizing the Format Settings on a TcxCustomDateEdit

Tags: delphi, custom-controls, devexpress

I'm looking to write a Date edit control preferably with a Date/Time picker that stores it's format settings on the control itself so they can be defined at run time independently from other controls.

I've TcxCustomDateEdit as a base and overridden various methods to handle the input and output but now I've hit a snag with the Popup Calendar, which shows all the month and Day Names using the variables in SysUtils.

I need to be able to use specific format settings (including the month and day names) instead of the system locale

Any idea's how I can get around this?

**EDIT**

I've included the 2 images below from the popup window from the TcxDateEdit.

ShortDateFormat: Date in the Top bar
ShortDayNames: First letter of each day in the calendar
LongMonthNames: The Month name between the Arrows for the current month, The list of month names in the MonthListPopup.

TimeSeparator: Should control the `:` in the TimeEdit but doesn't.

These are all part of TFormatSettings and I would like to control these at the individual control level.

[image][image]

Comment: please let me know how you want to customize the TcxCustomDateEdit class. I am afraid from your description it is unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @platon: I want to be able to specify the format settings for the control to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a new Popup Calendar

```
TMyPopupCalendar = class(TcxPopupCalendar);
```

and a new list box

```
TRegionalPopupListBox = class(TcxMonthListBox)
```

and in the date edit control overrode `CreateCalendar` and `GetCalendarClass`

Answer (score 0):

Aha, I now understand what you want to achieve.  Delphi's dateEdit uses the standard Delphi's ShortDateFormat to format a value.  I would start from overriding the TcxCustomDateEditProperties.PrepareDisplayValue, TcxCustomDateEditProperties.InternalPrepareEditValue and TcxCustomDateEditProperties.ValidateDisplayValue methods.

Comment: I've done that and it's working quite well, but the Popup Calendar still uses the sysutils variables.

Comment: do you mean the timeEdit which is residing in the popup?

Comment: No the TcxPopupCalendar and the TcxMonthListBox both use LongMonthNames.

Comment: could you please post the screenshot showing what you want to change?